# email design looking different in outlook in comparison to other email clients

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook, html-email

I am working on html emails in which I have replicated a design using html and inline styles.

**In the outlook, I am seeing the following design:**

[image]

**Design in the fiddle**:

Attached is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zg6xcky/3/) for that where I have mentioned all my html and inline styles. **In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zg6xcky/3/), I am getting the different design in comparison to the design (Outlook) above.**

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should do in the inline style of the fiddle so that the design in the fiddle and in the screenshot(outlook) above both looks the same.

The space beneath the text **Steps to earn your money** is too much in the outlook screenshot in comparison to the design in the fiddle. The snippets of code which I have used in that section are:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="padding-left:15%;padding-bottom:25%;">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <h2 style="text-align: left;
                  padding-left: 19%;
                  color: #484848;
                  padding-top: 2.5%;
                  padding-bottom: 5%;
                  padding-right: 12%;">steps to earn your money:</h2>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="text-align:left;color:#484848;font-size:20px;">
            <td>
               1. click here to open the XYZ app to the posting requests page<br><br>
               2. click on availability check request<br><br>
               3. say yes, its availabile ot suggest another date it is<br><br>
               4. wait the 1 or 24 hour confirmation good<br><br>
               5. three days after the booking ends money will be send to your account<br><br>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Did you try opening dev tools (F12) and inspecting the table in the email to see what styles are being applied?

Comment: @JosephWebber I have used litmus.com to do email testing and in it I have received screenshots for different clients.

Comment: @JosephWebber Yes, I did that. I am using inline styling and all the styles are mentioned there.

Comment: @JosephWebber In the outlook screenshot, it is creating an unnecessary space beneath `Steps to earn your money` text and it is shifted towards left as well, not sure why.

Comment: Outlook cannot support padding. You'll need to use other means to create spacing around your elements such as adding empty table rows/cols or adding `height`/`line-height`/`width`/`text-align` styles.

Comment: @JosephWebber Does outlook supports margin ?

Comment: No, it can't support margin either.

Comment: @JosephWebber Is there any we can fix that ? Because replacement of margin and padding such `height/line-height/width/text-align` will take huge amount of time to fix.

Comment: Nope, such is the pain of creating email templates.

Comment: @JosephWebber [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347803/margin-in-html-not-working-in-outlook) its written, we can use padding instead of margin.

Comment: I checked a few more sources and apparently padding _does_ work in Outlook, but only if you follow best practices. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474239/css-padding-is-not-working-in-outlook) post.

Comment: Aren't you simply haven't added "font-size" to your h2 style directly?

Because of that, outlook uses it's default h2 sizes, which in comparison to web standards is different.

Answer (score 2):

Had a quick check of your code and here is what i found:

1. You had the td and tr swapped at line 17 and 18 (just as Jason above mentioned)
2. You are using padding as percentage (line 55 i fixed). Its not a good idea, keep it at pixels for peace of mind. Change to pixels in other places as well.

```html
<html>
<body>


 
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="800" class="mobile"  align="center">

   <tr>
   <td>
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:6%;padding-bottom:5%;font-size:20px;color:#55BEC7;"> hi ABC,</td>
            
          </tr>
         
        </table>
</td>
  </tr>
  
 <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size:20px;padding-left:5%;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">type:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">availability check request</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">estimated total:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">what</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">chainsaw</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">how many</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">Mar 28/18 @ 7:00pm to <br> Mar 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">who:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;color:#FF8D58;">John s</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="padding-left:15%;padding-bottom:25%;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h2 style="text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #484848;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;">steps to earn your money:</h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align:left;color:#484848;font-size:20px;">
            <td>
                 1. click here to open the XYZ app to the posting requests page<br><br>
                 2. click on availability check request<br><br>
                 3. say yes, its availabile ot suggest another date it is<br><br>
                 4. wait the 1 or 24 hour confirmation good<br><br>
                 5. three days after the booking ends money will be send to your account<br><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Syfer, can you update it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zg6xcky/3/), whatever you want me to scrap (from your 1st point) ?

Comment: The padding will be dependent on your design. Change the padding from percentage to pixels.

Comment: If  you want me to remove line#17 and line#18, then do you want me to remove line# 7 and 8 as well ?

Comment: no, what does your design look like? Or what do you want it to look like? Just change the percentage value to pixels and it should change/fix it. Dont take the pixel value over 20px or it will look odd.